# Regex isn't working. Getting a stack overflow error

Tags: c#, regex

I found this pattern on the web, in addition to this pattern I've also tested several more, and they all fail, but they fail only on success.

```
public string Address { 
        get 
        {
            return this.Address;
        } 
        private set
        {
            string emailPattern = @"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*"
                                + "@"
                                + @"((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))"
                                + "|"
                                + @"(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\z";

            if (Regex.IsMatch(value, emailPattern))
            {
                this.Address = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(value + " doesn't seem to be a valid email address.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't in the regular expression's pattern, it's that if the regex matches you call your setter in an infinite loop. You would have the same issue by simply calling your getter. Use a backing field instead to avoid this situation.

```
private string _address;
public string Address 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return _address; 
    } 
    private set
    {
        string emailPattern = @"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*"
                            + "@"
                            + @"((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))"
                            + "|"
                            + @"(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\z";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(value, emailPattern))
        {
            _address = value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(value + " doesn't seem to be a valid email address.");
        }
    }
}
```

Stepping through your code in the debugger would have clearly shown the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this line youa re calling the set method and entering in a infinite loop:

```
this.Address = value;
```

You need to set in a private attribute:

```
private string _address = string.empty

public string Address { 
        get 
        {
            return _address;
        } 
        private set
        {
            string emailPattern = @"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*"
                                + "@"
                                + @"((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))"
                                + "|"
                                + @"(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))\z";

            if (Regex.IsMatch(value, emailPattern))
            {
                _address = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(value + " doesn't seem to be a valid email address.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: The getter will provoke a `StackOverflowException` as well!

Comment: Yeah , its really, sorry  I look only the setter

Answer (score 0):

Vache right with the infinite loop and rightly includes a backing field for the property in his example.

As a general rule, especially if using patterns such as MVVM, your setters should check for a value change to avoid infinite loops. An example of this being used in Microsoft documentation is in [BindableBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130657.aspx).

e.g.

```
if(_address != value)
  _address = value;
```

or:

```
if(_address == value)
  return;
_address = value;
```

Comment: That's good practice indeed, but it wouldn't have saved him here since he doesn't have a backing field and his value is never actually set.